# Explain PostgreSql ssl_cipher values: ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH

Tags: postgresql, configuration, ssl

In the `postgresql.conf` file, one can configure authorized values for `ssl_cipher`. Yet I could not find documentation explaining what the ALL, ADH, LOW, EXP, MD5 and STRENGTH values correspond to.

MD5 refers to the corresponding MD5 algorithm I guess, but what about the other values? I believe LOW should not be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a parameter that is processed by the OpenSSL library. The format and options are documented in the [`ciphers(5)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#) man page.

For the ones you mention:

> ALL
>
> all cipher suites except the eNULL ciphers which must be explicitly enabled; as of OpenSSL, the ALL cipher suites are reasonably ordered by default
>
> ADH
>
> anonymous DH cipher suites, note that this does not include anonymous Elliptic Curve DH (ECDH) cipher suites.
>
> LOW
>
> ``low'' encryption cipher suites, currently those using 64 or 56 bit encryption algorithms but excluding export cipher suites.
>
> EXP, EXPORT
>
> export encryption algorithms. Including 40 and 56 bits algorithms.
>
> MD5
>
> cipher suites using MD5.

You can combine them and specifically include or exclude classes of ciphers by using prefixes:

> Each cipher string can be optionally preceded by the characters !, -
>   or +.
>
> If ! is used then the ciphers are permanently deleted from the list.
>   The ciphers deleted can never reappear in the list even if they are
>   explicitly stated.
>
> If - is used then the ciphers are deleted from the list, but some or
>   all of the ciphers can be added again by later options.
>
> If + is used then the ciphers are moved to the end of the list. This
>   option doesn't add any new ciphers it just moves matching existing
>   ones.

`@STRENGTH` is a bit special:

> The cipher string @STRENGTH can be used at any point to sort the current cipher list in order of encryption algorithm key length.